# Python: Generate a thumbnail from the last frame in AWS MediaConvert

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

The videos I have are of different sizes and different frame rates. I would like to create a thumbnail from the last frame of the vides regardless of their size or FPS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, for each job you will need to know the framerate and frame number of the final frame. Please see link below which explains how to create a poster frame at a specific frame number:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/create-a-poster-frame-and-thumbnail-images-for-videos-using-aws-elemental-mediaconvert/

Comment: These docs seem to be out of date